# Controller SlideMenu on Sencha

Tags: extjs, controller

Help me :(
I've been researching on how to reference methods of a button using MVC on Sencha Touch, but none of the articles has worked fine for me since I declare all my controls on the constructor of my views.

View :

```
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'main',
requires:   [
                'Ext.Menu',
                'Ext.Img',
                'Ext.Toolbar',
                'Ext.Container'
            ],
config: {
    scrollable: true,
    type: 'card',
    fullscreen : true,
    html: [
        '<img max width="100%" height="auto" src="resources/image/Head.png" />',
        '<h1>STMIK Akakom Yogyakarta</h1>',
        '<h1><img max width="40%" height="auto" src="resources/image/Logo.png"/> </h1>'
    ],

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Selamat Datang',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    iconCls: 'list',
                    ui: 'plain',
                    action : 'slideMenu'

                }
            ]

        },
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked:'bottom'
        }
    ],

},
```

Controller :

```
        config: {
            views: [
                'Main',
                'MenuNav',
                'HalamanUtama'
            ],
            refs: {
                main: {
                    selector:'main',
                    xtype:'main',
                    autoCreate: true
                },
                menunav:{
                    selector:'menunav',
                    xtype: 'menunav',
                    autoCreate: true
                },
                halamanutama: {
                    selector: 'halamanutama',
                    xtype: 'halamanutama',
                    autoCreate: true
                }
            },
            controll: {
                'button[ui=plain]':{
                    tap: 'slideMenu'
                },
                'button=action[MenuNavOption]': {
                    tap: 'handleNavigation'
                }
            }
        },
        initialize: function(){
            var menuNav = this.getNav();
            Ext.Viewport.setMenu(menuNav,{
                side: 'left',
                reveal: true
            });
        },
        slideMenu: function(){
            if(Ext.Viewport.getMenus().left.isHidden())
                {
                    Ext.Viewport.showMenu('left');
                }
                else
                {
                    Ext.Viewport.hideMenu('left');
                }
        },
        handleNavigation: function(button){
            switch(button.getText()){
                case 'HalamanUtama' :
                    var halamanutamaView = Ext.Viewport.child('halamanutama');
                    if (!halamanutamaView) {
                        halamanutamaView = this.getHalamanutama();
                        Ext.Viewport.add(halamanutamaView);
                    }
                    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(halamanutamaView);
                    break;
                default : 
                    var mainView = Ext.Viewport.child('main');
                    if(!mainView){
                        mainView = this.getMain();
                        Ext.Viewport.add(mainView);
                    }
                    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(mainView);
            }
            this.hideNav();
        }
}
```

but still my slide menu did not show up :( please can you show me the way. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.